# sql split 5 values on delimiter

Tags: sql, string, split, common-table-expression, delimiter

So i have this code that splits exactly 4 values on double delimiter , it works perfectly , but i cant get around how to split 5 values
Here is my string

```
@string = 'Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4|Value5, OtherVal1|OtherVal2|OtherVal3|OtherVal4|OtherVal5'
```

Here is code i have for spliting 4 values

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Replace(Rtrim(Ltrim(split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))), '|','.') AS split_data 
         FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@string, ',', '</M><M>') 
                              + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A 
                CROSS apply data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) 
SELECT COLUMN2= Parsename(split_data, 4), 
       COLUMN3=Parsename(split_data, 3), 
       COLUMN4= Parsename(split_data, 2), 
       COLUMN5=Parsename(split_data, 1) 
FROM   cte
```

How do i split it on 5 vals ?

Comment: isn't it just adding a COLUMNX = Parsename(split_data, 5), ?

Comment: @Turo no. parsename will only work with 4 parts.

Comment: You need to split the string into rows and then pivot the split results into columns. BTW, this is yet another example why you should never use delimited data in sql.

Comment: @ZoharPeled How do i do that then ? Thank you for your time

Comment: silly me, but you could write a stored function wich splits with delimiter and positions as you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first look...

Seems, you have to use [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) twice. First one - to get "rows" (split data by `,`) and the second one - to get "colums" (split data by `|`). Then you have to [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140308.aspx) data to display them in tabular form ;)

Have a look at example:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4|Value5, OtherVal1|OtherVal2|OtherVal3|OtherVal4|OtherVal5'

;WITH MyRows AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS RowNo, LEFT(@string, CHARINDEX(', ', @string)-1) AS MyVals, RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(', ', @string)) AS Remainder
    WHERE CHARINDEX(', ', @string)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowNo + 1 AS RowNo, LEFT(Remainder, CHARINDEX(', ', Remainder)) AS MyVals, RIGHT(Remainder, LEN(Remainder) - CHARINDEX(', ', Remainder)) AS Remainder
    FROM MyRows
    WHERE CHARINDEX(', ', Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowNo + 1 AS RowNo, Remainder AS MyVals, NULL AS Remainder
    FROM MyRows
    WHERE CHARINDEX(', ', Remainder)=0
),
    MyCols AS
    (
        SELECT RowNo, 1 AS ColNumber,  LEFT(MyVals, CHARINDEX('|', MyVals)-1) AS SingleValue, RIGHT(MyVals, LEN(MyVals) - CHARINDEX('|', MyVals)) AS Remainder
        FROM MyRows 
        WHERE CHARINDEX('|', MyVals)>0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RowNo, ColNumber + 1 AS ColNumber, LEFT(Remainder, CHARINDEX('|', Remainder)-1) AS SingleValue, RIGHT(Remainder, LEN(Remainder) - CHARINDEX('|', Remainder)) AS Remainder
        FROM MyCols
        WHERE CHARINDEX('|', Remainder)>0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RowNo, ColNumber + 1 AS ColNumber, Remainder AS SingleValue, NULL AS Remainder
        FROM MyCols
        WHERE CHARINDEX('|', Remainder)=0
    )
SELECT RowNo, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
FROM (
    SELECT ColNumber, SingleValue, RowNo
    FROM MyCols ) AS DT
PIVOT(Max(SingleValue) FOR ColNumber IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) AS PT
```

Result:

```
RowNo    1          2           3           4           5
1        Value1     Value2      Value3      Value4      Value5
2        OtherVal1  OtherVal2   OtherVal3   OtherVal4   OtherVal5
```